# How do I edit SSIS package files?

Tags: ssis

I have a DTSX file in a project I'm taking over. I have Visual Studio 2005 Pro, but it just opens it as an XML file. SQL Server Management Studio 2005 does the same.

I've seen people opening these files in some workflow-esque format; Business Intelligence Development Studio comes to mind.

Is this part of Visual Studio or SQL? Does it have to be purchased seperately? Can I open this file in a more useful way with the tools I have?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From **Business Intelligence Studio**:

File->New Project->Integration Services Project

Now in solution explorer there is a SSIS Packages folder, right click it and select "Add Existing Package", and there will be a drop down that can be changed to File System, and the very bottom box allows you to browse to the file.  Note that this will copy the file from where ever it is into the project's directory structure.

If you need to open a *.dtsx file in **SSDT**, then see:
[How do I open a DTSX file in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223620/how-do-i-open-a-dtsx-file-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: Business Intelligence Studio is not available any more and in last years replaced by SQL Server Data Tools. See answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/40323983/52277

Answer (score 20):

Current for 2016 link is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

**[SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/mt186501) is** a modern development tool that you can download for free to build SQL Server relational databases, Azure SQL databases, **Integration Services packages**, Analysis Services data models, and Reporting Services reports. With **SSDT**, you can design and deploy any SQL Server content type with the same ease as you would develop an application in Visual Studio.
This release supports SQL Server 2016 through SQL Server 2005, and provides the design environment for adding features that are new in SQL Server 2016.

Note that you don't need to have Visual Studio pre-installed.  SSDT will install required components of VS, if it is not installed on your machine.

This release supports SQL Server 2016 through SQL Server 2005, and provides the design environment for adding features that are new in SQL Server 2016

Previously included in SQL Server standalone Business Intelligence Studio is not available any more and in last years replaced by SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio. See answer http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/q-where-business-intelligence-development-studio-bids-sql-server-2014

Answer (score 14):

Additional answer for Visual Studio 2012:

You can open .dtsx along with their corresponding .dtproj project files with the SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence (SSDT-BI) add-in:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2013/03/07/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2012-released-online.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=36843

If the projects were created with an earlier version they will require an upgrade.

I did have some hang ups installing this - the install would spin on "Install_VSTA2012_CPU32_Action" and similar steps.  It wasn't until I did a repair inside of the same installer did it install completely.

Answer (score 8):

Adding to what b_levitt said, you can get the SSDT-BI plugin for Visual Studio 2013 here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: Note that the VS 2013 plugin is for targeting SQL Server 2014.  You need to use VS 2012 to manage projects intended to target SQL 2012.

Answer (score 7):

You need the Business Intelligence Studio ..I've checked and my version of VS2008 Pro doesn't have them installed.

Have a look at this link:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3C856B93-369F-4C6F-9357-C35384179543&displaylang=en

Comment: -1 for the second link which blocks the answer unless you sign up, free option is a 30-day account which i have already used over a year ago, do not understand why one would have a link on a free Q&A site to another Q&A site which isn't free

Comment: The link is outdated, see SSDT for VS 2015 answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/40323983/52277

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use :

(from SSDT visual studio just opened)
file> open > file > locate dtsx file > open

then you can edit work and save

Answer (score 1):

If you use the 'Export Data' wizard there is an option to store the configuration as an 'Integration Services Projects' within the SQL Server database .  To edit this package follow the instructions from "mikeTheLiar" but instead of searching for a file make a connection to the database and export package.

From "mikeTheLiar":
*File->New Project->Integration Services Project -
Now in solution explorer there is a SSIS Packages folder, right click it and select "Add Existing Package".*

Using the default dialog make a connection to the database and open the export package.  The package can now be edited.