# SSIS package edit

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an one data transfer package with .DTSX extension.
I want to edit that package.

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829101/how-do-i-edit-ssis-package-files

Comment: You can edit the XML in notepad, or if you know the version, you can edit it in Visual Studio (BIDS) or SQL Server Data Tools. Start by downloading SQL Server Data Tools

Comment: Open the file in notepad and look for the property `PackageFormatVersion`, you can determine what version of SSIS it was written for by that number. (Search online for translation.)

Answer (score 3):

DTS was the old extension name used for Integration Services packages.
DTSX is new (I guess my new! refers to SQL2005)

With recent releases SQL Server introduced [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn864412) which is very similar to Visual Studio but concentrated on SQL Server tasks.

SQL Server Business Intelligence developers can use [SQL Server Data Tools](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/sql-server-data-tools-installation-for-visual-studio.aspx) for creating and editing Analysis Services, Integration Services and Reporting Services solutions

[image]

Here is a download [link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=832308)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

1. Open BIDS or SSDT (it depends which version of sql server development tool you have installed)
2. Create a new Sql Server Integration Project
3. copy the .dtsx package by pressing Ctrl + c and go back to the newly created project , you will see the portion "Package" in Solution Explorer , Paste your copied package here by selecting the "Package" header.
4. double click to this copied package, you can now edit your package.