# Problems opening a dtsx file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017, ssis-2017

When I open a dtsx file in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 it opens them as just an XML file.  I read over [this stack overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829101/how-do-i-edit-ssis-package-files) but when I do a File->New Project I don't see Integration Services Project as an option.  I checked the Visual Studio Installer and I see that **Data storage and processing** is already installed.  SQL Server Data Tools is checked too:

[image: Installation Details]

Is there something else that I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have installed SQL Server Data Tools without checking the Integration Services from the installer.

[image]

- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#install-ssdt-with-visual-studio-2017)

Also try using the standalone installer *(check the link above for more details)*

Comment: Would it work then to uncheck the Data storage and processing from the Installer, let it uninstall the feature, and then reinstall the feature making sure to check the Integration Services from the installer?

Comment: I just tried that and didn't see the dialog you posted appear.

Comment: @Eric this is the standalone installer. Try it

Comment: I did the standalone installer and Visual Studio recognized the file.  I opened it and got an error (sorry I don't remember what it was).  After a reboot it looks good.

Comment: Here is the link for versions prior to 2019: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-ver16